# memcached: CACHE.stats[:curr_items] often decreases

Tags: ruby, memcached

We use Memcached in our Ruby on Rails app.  I'm trying to look into it in a bit more detail and at the end of each request I log out the value of `CACHE.stats[:curr_items]` which **i think** is the number of saved items in the cache.

I record the value of `CACHE.stats[:curr_items]` at the start and end of the request, which allows me to see how many new things were saved into the cache in that request (page load).  Quite often, this is a negative number - that is, the value of `CACHE.stats[:curr_items]` has decreased.

I can't work out why it would ever decrease.  We don't ever delete any cache keys, and I can't imagine why it would decrease just by reloading the same page anyway.

I would also expect `CACHE.stats[:curr_items]` to go to 0 after doing `CACHE.flush`, but it stays the same.

I've got another way of listing the current memcache keys, which makes a telnet connection to memcache and uses `stats items` and `stats cachedump` to list the current keys.  This number is generally different to `CACHE.stats[:curr_items]`, and, again, doesn't go to zero if I do `CACHE.flush`.

Can anyone explain what `CACHE.stats[:curr_items]` actually does?

Also, why do neither of these methods go to zero after `CACHE.flush`?  Maybe CACHE.flush invalidates the cache keys but doesn't actually remove them.  That's fair enough, and makes sense, if that is the case.

**EDIT**: I just did an experiment:

```
> CACHE.stats[:curr_items]
=> [529]
> CACHE.stats[:total_items]
=> [1080]
> stored = CACHE.add("qwrexcv#{rand(10000000)}", User.last, 604800)
=> nil
> CACHE.stats[:curr_items]
=> [529]
> CACHE.stats[:total_items]
=> [1081]
```

So, i've added a new thing to the cache.  curr_items has stayed the same and total_items has incremented, giving further support to the idea that curr_items isn't what I think it is.

Comment: Sure you use memcached only? For clearing memcached its has to be `Rails.cache.clear` .What is actually `CACHE`? You are right stats[:curr_items] shows the current items. Testable by just `Rails.cache.fetch('key') do; User.first; end` after this is should have increased by 1

Comment: Also check if your memcached config has the key `expires_in` then the keys auto expire.

Comment: Thanks - I am using a very old version of ruby (1.8.7) and rails (2.2.2) with this project, and CACHE is how I access memcached via rails.  I can access it with Rails.cache but I don't have access to the stats that way.

Comment: see my edit, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [memcached docs](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt#L667) `curr_items` shows the number of items currently in the cache. `total_items` is the number of all items that were saved since the server started.

As far as I can tell there are four ways for the `curr_items` counter to decrease: (i) by deleting a key, (ii) by flushing, (iii) by expiration, and (iv) by downsizing the memory available to the memcached server. Eviction generally does not decrease the items because an item is generally evicted to make space for a new one.

The `flush_all` memcached command does set the `curr_items` counter to 0, at least in memcached 1.5. You can verify that with a telnet connection. The behavior might be different for memcached 1.4 as a lot has changed from version 1.4 to 1.5.